Why is there a difference of vertical offset between two ImGUI Text components
I am trying to display two slidebar for my X and Y positions in ImGUI.
And while the "Y :" label seems to be correctly centered, the "Position" and the "X :" label seems to be a bit high as compared to the other one.
I tried to display the current position of the player using ImGUI but there is a difference in the position of labels although they were all instanciated the same way and I don't understand why.
I cannot find what is causing that.
Here is the minimal code required to reproduce the problem :
#include "imgui.h"
#include "backends/imgui_impl_sdl2.h"
#include "backends/imgui_impl_sdlrenderer.h"
#include <SDL.h>

#if !SDL_VERSION_ATLEAST(2,0,17)
#error This backend requires SDL 2.0.17+ because of SDL_RenderGeometry() function
#endif

// Main code
int main(int, char**)
{
    // Setup SDL
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_GAMECONTROLLER);

    // From 2.0.18: Enable native IME.
#ifdef SDL_HINT_IME_SHOW_UI
    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_IME_SHOW_UI, "1");
#endif

    // Create window with SDL_Renderer graphics context
    SDL_WindowFlags window_flags = (SDL_WindowFlags)(SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Dear ImGui SDL2+SDL_Renderer example", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1280, 720, window_flags);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    // Setup Dear ImGui context
    IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
    ImGui::CreateContext();

    // Setup Dear ImGui style
    ImGui::StyleColorsDark();

    // Setup Platform/Renderer backends
    ImGui_ImplSDL2_InitForSDLRenderer(window, renderer);
    ImGui_ImplSDLRenderer_Init(renderer);

    // Variables for the game
    float realPosPlayerShip[2] = { 0.0f, 0.0f };
    SDL_Rect dstPlayerShip = {};

    // Main loop
    bool done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            ImGui_ImplSDL2_ProcessEvent(&event);

            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                done = true;
            if (event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT && event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE && event.window.windowID == SDL_GetWindowID(window))
                done = true;
        }

        ImGui_ImplSDLRenderer_NewFrame();
        ImGui_ImplSDL2_NewFrame();
        ImGui::NewFrame();

        ImGui::Begin("Player Settings");

        ImGui::Text("Window for debugging player settings");
        ImGui::Separator();
        ImGui::Separator();

        // LABELING DATA
        ImGui::Text("Position");
        ImGui::SameLine();

        // X POSITION MODIFIER
        ImGui::Text("X : ");
        ImGui::SameLine();
        ImGui::PushItemWidth(90.0f);
        ImGui::SliderFloat("##Posx", &realPosPlayerShip[0], 0.0f, 1280.0f);
        ImGui::PopItemWidth();
        ImGui::SameLine();

        // Y POSITION MODIFIER
        ImGui::Text("Y : ");
        ImGui::SameLine();
        ImGui::PushItemWidth(90.0f);
        ImGui::SliderFloat("##Posy", &realPosPlayerShip[1], 0.0f, 720.0f);
        ImGui::PopItemWidth();

        ImGui::End();

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 1);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        ImGui::Render();
        ImGui_ImplSDLRenderer_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    ImGui_ImplSDLRenderer_Shutdown();
    ImGui_ImplSDL2_Shutdown();
    ImGui::DestroyContext();

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}

This gives me the following result :

I don't understand why this problem occurs as the "Y :" component is created the exact same way as the others. I can't seem to find a solution to solve this problem either.

https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/issues/6127


I don't understand why this problem occurs as the "Y :" component is created the exact same way as the others. I can't seem to find a solution to solve this problem either.

You need to be calling AlignTextToFramePadding() before the first one to set the text baseline. See Demo->Layout->Text Baseline Alignment
The reason is that ImGui has no knowledge of what's coming next and it's drawing items as you submit them.
